# What does "call to adventure" mean?

Tags: meaning

Does "call" mean "invitation" or something? I've looked it up in several dictionaries to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

There are many stories in which the hero is *destined* to do great deeds and have grand adventures. And a common way to describe how the hero is made aware of this destiny is as a *call* to the adventure, quest, etc. This is part invitation and part command: the hero is expected to be at least somewhat willing, but it's not exactly an invitation to a garden party.

See [sense 8 in the Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/call_1?q=call#call_1__376), especially the third example of being called to the priesthood (which is closely analogous).

In fact, the word *vocation*, which is like "career" but more idealistic, and thus well-suited to describing what a hero does with their life, comes from the Latin word for "call".

Answer (score 1):

I think that Nathan has nailed it. He has linked the Oxford Learners Dictionary but let check the Oxford Dictionary sense 6

**[call](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/call)** [noun]

> 6. An order or request for someone to be present
>
>    6.1 A vocation
>
>    6.2 **A powerful force of attraction**

If you feel a **call to adventure**, you have a [calling](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/calling), you feel *a strong **urge** towards a particular way of life*, an **adventuring** life. "Life" may be exaggerated, maybe you just need a bit of adventure during holidays, it depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the example of [the tabletop game](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/brotherwise/call-to-adventure-featuring-name-of-the-wind) that uses the name "Call to adventure".

I suppose the use of *call* here is the [number nine in the Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/call_1?q=call): *make a (short) visit to an adventure (not in this world)*.
I understand it as a sweet **escape** into fantastic worlds in this sense.